# How to find the css code which makes images dark on my website?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I need help with my Wordpress website. Theme, which I am currently using, automatically makes background images dark (in elements with text and button). With bright pictures it's ok, but with dark ones it looks horrible. How to find the stylesheet with the corresponding css and how to make it less dark? It's the same situation as in the demo here: [Total Vanilla theme demo](https://total.wpexplorer.com/vanilla/)

Comment: Please put some efford into your own reasearch. You should already know how to use a F12 insepctor and how to style with css. The communtiy will help you with specific problems but not with very basic stuff like giving you an entire base tutorial to styling.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to inspect the image and you will jump to the right html element. In your case it's this element that cause the dark effect:

```html
<span class="wpex-bg-overlay color" style="background-color:#383d47;opacity:0.8;" data-style="background-color:#383d47;opacity:0.8;"></span>
```

To quickly mask all of them you can use this css:

```css
.wpex-bg-overlay {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Open your website in the browser and press F12 to open the inspector. There you have every piece of code of your website including the CSS files (which will be in the header with a link to a file ending with .css.

in your case:

> https://total.wpexplorer.com/vanilla/wp-content/themes/Total/style.css?ver=4.9.9.1